# Having an import error with discord.py

Tags: python, importerror, discord

I'm trying to build a discord bot, and I have this error that I can't seem to figure out that explicitly happens when I try to import discord.py

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Pastry/PycharmProjects/PastryBot/sample.py", line 1, in <module>
import discord
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 28, in <module>
from .user import User
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\user.py", line 27, in <module>
from .utils import snowflake_time
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 31, in <module>
import asyncio
File "C:\Python35\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from .base_events import *
File "C:\Python35\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
import concurrent.futures
File "C:\Python35\lib\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
File "C:\Python35\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 55, in <module>
from multiprocessing.connection import wait
File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 18, in <module>
import tempfile
File "C:\Python35\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name 'Random'
```

I tried using the sample code from the [quickstart bot guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot) on their documentation page as well, and ran into the same error. I thought it was a problem with my version of discord.py so I tried to update it, and then re-ran the program but I'm still getting this error. Could anyone help enlighten me?

Comment: do you have a file named `random.py`  in your working directory ?

Comment: ... well, now I feel stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the discord.py library? that could be the the problem. What about the asyncio library? Those two are most likely.